# selenium C#, How to initialize a list of IWebElement widgets which have inner IWebElements?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, pom.xml

So I have a list of result widgets that get returned from a query.

Each result is a web element which has web elements inside of it.
(Each result is a profile for which I have a class...)

```
public class Profile
{
    [FindsBy(How = How.Class, Using = "title")]
    public IWebElement title;

    [FindsBy(How = How.Class, Using = "description")]
    public IWebElement description;

   [FindsBy(How = How.Class, Using = "image")]
    public IWebElement image;

}


<ul id="search_results">
    <li class="search_result"><span class="title">title</span> <div class="image"><img src="something.jpg"/></div> <span class="description"></span></li>
    <li class="search_result"><div><span>title</span> <div class="image"><img src="something.jpg"/></div> <span class="description"></span></li>
    <li class="search_result"><div><span>title</span> <div class="image"><img src="something.jpg"/></div> <span class="description"></span></li>
<ul>


[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "li.search_result")]
public IList<IWebElements> results; //OR? public IList<Profile> results;
```

...
?

Each result also has WebElements inside of it... 
I want to initialize a list of widgets plus all the inner web elements using Selenium... Is there some way I could do this automatically?

I could get Selenium to get the elements for me and them parse them manually and create Profile objects myself, but I am hoping to get Selenium to do this for me.

Comment: I don't think this is possible but maybe someone will know how to do it. A question... you realize that the HTML for the three `li.search_result` elements are not the same? There's an extra `DIV` before the first `SPAN` in the last two. Your last `FindBy` for image is not going to find the `IMG` tag... it's going to find the `DIV` that contains the `image` class. If you want the `IMG` tag you can do this using `[FindsBy(How = How.CssSelector, Using = "div.image > img")]`.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I see it... I just typed in some quick code to illustrate my point